# Geometric interpretation of product of the orthogonal vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

Let $x,y \in R^n$ (vectors)

$||x||_2 \neq 0$ and $||y||_2 \neq 0$

If $x$ orthogonal $y$ then $x^Ty = 0$

I understand how to prove it allegorically.
But I can't explain it to myself from geometrical side.

Can someone help me/explain me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Without loss of generality, assume $\|y\|_2=1$.** The value of $|x^Ty|$ is in fact length of the orthogonal projection of $x$ along $y$.

[image]

In the figure above, the length of the red segment is $x^Ty$. When $x^Ty$ is $0$, it means that $x$ is orthogonal to $y$.